# retrive different tables from sqlite database and show in combobox and clicking on table show data in JTable

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

I have multiple tables in my SQLite database. I want retrieve all tables from database to combobox and when I click on jComboBox and select any table it must show all data in JTable below (I am using Netbeans) please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

Code below will give you list of all tables from database.

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

Then add onChange() event on combobox.

Everytime user select the table Fire select query on database like

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
```

Then Create table dynamically.
If you want column name of the table then  you can get from table meta data.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

For JTable you can add row and column dynamically using following sample code.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "status", "Task Title", "Start", "Stop", "Pause", "Status" },0);
tblTaskList.setModel(model);
for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
     model.addRow(new Object[]{ count, "title1", "start", "stop", "pause", "status" });
}
```

Above will work fine.